# Online SEO checker reporting no title

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engines

I am new to SEO. I have created a WordPress Website and I have used a SEO checker online and get this issue:

```
Title: No Title. Important: Remember to set a title, never forget this
```

However I have set the title... how can this issue be resolved?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "check the SEO score online"? Where are you checking your online SEO score as you will find that almost every place you check scores on will provide you with different results based on the tests they are performing and the algorithms they use to calculate an "SEO score".

Comment: Your SEO score checker may be referring to deeper pages on the site that don't currently have title tags, I can see that your homepage does have the title correctly set up. In reference to DwillX's comment, be wary of the online 'score checkers' they're never an absolute solution, and often have a hidden agenda i.e. to sell software.

Comment: Did it cross your mind that the SEO checker could be the issue?

Comment: Check the obvious..... Are there visible characters between `<title>` and `</title>` on every page you are checking with this SEO tool?

Comment: Most, if not all, SEO evaluation sites are junk. There can be some value in some and you will have to figure which ones offer what value. Always take them with a lot of salt. If you know you have a title, do not freak out. If your title shows up in Googles SERPs for the snippet, then you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

How can you know if you have set the title appropriately:

- You look in the HTML source code for the page and see a `<title>` tag like the tag for this page: `<title>google webmaster tools - Online SEO checker reporting no title - Webmasters Stack Exchange</title>`
- The title appears in tabs the browser title bar in your web browser:[image]

If those are both fine, then you have set the page title correctly.   Keep in mind that *every* page on your site needs to have a descriptive and unique page title.   You have to worry about more than just the home page.

If your page checks out manually, then it is likely the checking tool you are using that has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Right click on anywhere in the page.
2. Hit "Inspect Element".
3. Scroll to the top of the webpage HTML.
4. Open up the `title` element by clicking on the carrot on the left.  If you can't see any carrot that you can click on, it means that you forgot to set the title.
5. Close the Developer Tools and then look in the browser title bar.
6. Hover on the title bar. If it shows your title, you have your title. Otherwise if you see some part of the URL as the title bar that means that you haven't set the title.

Repeat these steps for every webpage of yours until you've checked all of them.